# Filtering JSON onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
        $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
          for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
            var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview;
            var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
            $('#twitch').append('<li><iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/? channel=' + streamVideo + '"
     frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378"
     width="620"></iframe><li>');
          }});
```

So I've got this script which pulls streams from the Twitch API JSON. How can I filter them? Ex. Clicking on League of Legends displays only LoL streams etcetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering those results probably won't do what you want, as the number of results for any particular game will vary dependent on the current point in time.

With the twitch streams api, you can pass a search parameter like so:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=League%20of%20Legends
```

Empty your $('#twitch') element with each getJSON invocation, and reload from the data returned from the updated query.

```
function loadStreams(gameName) {
    var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";

    if (gameName) twitchApi += '?game=' + encodeURI(gameName);

    $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
         $('#twitch').empty()
         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
             var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview;
             var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
             $('#twitch').append('<li><iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/? channel=' + streamVideo + '"
                 frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378"
                 width="620"></iframe><li>');
    }});
}
```

Comment: Could you provide me with a script which does that? Empties #twitch on click and replaces it with those search parameters? @neil cross

Comment: how's that look? just add onclick="loadStreams('League of Legends')" to your link

Comment: Yes but uhm, I want it to display all streams when you open the website, I don't need an empty container. It should list out all streams and then if I click on a link ( LoL ) it should only return LoL streams.

Comment: ok, i assumed you had that in place already.  Something like adding onload="loadStreams()" to your body tag will do what you're asking.  If you don't pass a parameter into the method, the query will return streams from all games.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a fun answer but you can just resubmit the $.getJSON with the game in the url  like https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=League%20of%20Legends

Comment: Could you provide me with a script which does that? Empties #twitch on click and replaces it with those search parameters? @Do Nothing